# Inconsistent \baselineskip spacing above and below an image

Tags: spacing, align

I want the spacing between the text and the image, both at the top and bottom, to be consistent and equal to one `\baselineskip`. While the bottom spacing appears correct when compared to other spacings in the text, the top spacing is noticeably smaller. How can I rectify this discrepancy?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[
    font=normalsize,
    justification=raggedright,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    format=hang,
    labelsep=endash,
    figurewithin=none,
    tablewithin=none,
]{caption}
\RequirePackage[style=abnt]{biblatex}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \setlength{\intextsep}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\floatsep}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\jot}{\baselineskip}
}
\addbibresource{Referencias.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Experimento 4}
\author{Lucas Martins Soares}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introdução}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
        \caption{\label{fig:Stack} Pilha de Tecnologias utilizadas em Big Data}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Imagens/Stack.png}
        \caption*{\footnotesize Fonte: \textcite{sun2023survey}.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tex mostly is not concerned about the lengths you marked, it is mostly based on baseline-to-baseline space.

Comment: I get `! Argument of \caption@@@withoptargs has an extra }.` from your example (after changing the image to `example-image`)

Answer (score 2):

The document as posted had errors so no reliable output but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[
    font=normalsize,
    justification=raggedright,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    format=hang,
    labelsep=endash,
    figurewithin=none,
    tablewithin=none,
]{caption}
\RequirePackage[style=abnt]{biblatex}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \setlength{\intextsep}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\floatsep}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\textfloatsep}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\jot}{\baselineskip}
}
\addbibresource{Referencias.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Experimento 4}
\author{Lucas Martins Soares}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introdução}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
   % \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
        \caption{ Pilha de Tecnologias utilizadas em Big Data}\label{fig:Stack}
        \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption*{\footnotesize Fonte: \textcite{sun2023survey}.}
    %\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

adding

```
\showoutput
\showboxdepth=4
```

produces

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 m
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\penalty 0
...\glue 12.0
...\vbox(182.10617+0.0)x345.0
....\vbox(182.10617+0.0)x345.0 []
...\penalty 0
...\glue 12.0
...\glue 0.0 plus -1.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.05556
...\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 0.85849
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 L
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 o
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 r
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 m
```

showing the effect of the spacing is to add 12pt above the float, 12pt below,  and an additional 5pt below, which combined with 7pt height of the `L` gives a 12pt space to the baseline of the following text.

Any other white space is within the float so not affected by the document level float spacing parameters.